# Bundling HTML, CSS and Javascript into one js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a form component, without any frameworks, and want to distribute it to clients with a single js file. All they would have to do is create a div with a specific id and my js would inject the html of my component into that div.

Instead of writing vanilla js 'document.createElement' a bunch of times I just want to write the html then build it and combine it into a single js file.

Is this the right approach? How can this be achieved?

Comment: This isn't the best approach, doing this is going to make it very difficult to manage the code and keep it updated. On top of that .JS file would only be able to produce the strings that contain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If all your files are hosted in online, your JS file can load each file on init. So you'll be distributing a single JS file (or the link of an hosted JS file), and it will load his component by itself.